Why is Configuring a Source Interface "Necessary" or Recommended for NTP?
I know it isn't essential to configure a source interface when setting up NTP, but how does it help in practice? Why is it often configured on loopback addresses when we've already updated the system calendar or peered with different low-stratum servers?

This is not just for NTP, but for many protocols/services in your router. Setting sources on a loopback interface is a best practice because loopback addresses never go down (unless, of course, you manually take them down).
If you source things by letting them just use the default outbound interface address, and that interface goes down, then a new (different) connection from a different interface will need to be established, and that will interrupt the protocol/service using the downed source address.
When you source from a loopback interface and the default outbound interface for a protocol/service goes down, the protocol/service could use another interface to accomplish the same connection that is based on the loopback address, and it would not need to create a new connection that would interrupt the service/protocol.
NTP will establish a peer with an NTP server based on the outbound interface address unless you specify a different source address. If that interface fails, and you have another path to the peer, then you must establish a new (different) peering based on the new outbound interface address. By using a loopback interface, the source address of the peering will be the loopback interface address, and it will not change if the default outbound interface fails and the path changes, so you will not need to create a new peering.

Also note that for any NTP server stratum 2 or worse, the REFID is the IP address of the server (or truncated address in the case of IPv6), and thus might change as well if you don't use a stable address.
